# Why does Swift's typechecking system allow a function that returns a type to not return anything?

Tags: swift, typechecking, type-systems

Why does the following code works?

```
func square(_ x: Int) -> Int {
  fatalError()
}
```

fatalError() never returns anything (or rather it returns Never). Why would the type system not catch an issue here that the func does not return an Int even though it says it would?

Comment: On the flip-side, this can actually be very useful for stubbing a method in the middle of a TDD cycle.

Comment: It is useful but I am trying to understand why the type checking is not failing for this.

Comment: Is it acceptable enough to just answer "because the type system was designed that way *precisely* because it's pragmatic"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because [`fatalError`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/1538698-fatalerror) returns [`Never`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/never). From the documentation, `Never` is,

> The return type of functions that do not return normally, that is, a type with no values.

Through compiler magic, Swift understands that `fatalError` "does not return normally", namely that it crashes the app. This is why it does not complain about `square` not returning an `Int`.

If a path of your function call a function that "does not return normally", that path does not return normally either. "Does not return normally" means that the caller won't be able to use the return value, so there is no point in enforcing the "you must return a value" rule in that path of your function.

Comment: So, what your are saying is _the behavior of calling a function returning Never is the same, in terms of type system (outflow type) and branch analysis, as calling throw_? Please don’t delete comments out of spite - it is both rude and destruction of valid information.

Comment: @user2864740 In terms of branch analysis, yes, but I'm not sure about type system. A `throw` statement does not have a type (because it's a _statement_), but a method call to a `Never`-returning method does have a type (because it's an _expression_), namely `Never`. You can pass `fatalError()` to a function accepting an unconstrained generic parameter `T`, but you can't do that with a `throw` statement, because it's not an expression.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that a `throw` can be conceptualized as having a Never type. It works in the same manner as further code execution, including a potential return, after a `throw` is simply illogical.

```
func square(_ x: Int) -> Int {
    throw TooManyDotsError()
}
```

**Also accepting this behavior when calling a function typed as [`-> Never`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/never) allows the same unification between `throw` and `fatalError()`.**

> Use Never as the return type when declaring a closure, function, or method that *unconditionally throws an error [as the `throw` statement does], traps, or otherwise does not terminate*.

The return type of a method says that **if** the method  returns, it must return a value of the given type. Calling a “Never” method, as with `throw`, *precludes returning* on the given branch.

To show how this is useful, compare the language without this built into the type system, such as C#:

```
int F() {
    // guaranteed to throw, but not known to type system
    AlwaysThrow();
    // dummy throw to appease type system
    throw Exception("Not reachable");
}
```

Comment: Why are you talking about `throw` when the question asks about `fatalError`?

Comment: This answer explains the behavior (with a rational justification, _using_ throw as an example) — and _the OP already acknowledges the return of fatalError is Never_.

Comment: I *have* read the whole answer, and I understand the point you are trying to make, but  starting off by talking about the tangentially related `throw` statement, is quite confusing in my opinion...